# Two EntityGraph on same class is not working (EclipseLink)

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

Iam trying to add a second EntityGraph on my class.

```
 @NamedEntityGraph( name = "foo.details", attributeNodes = {
                    @NamedAttributeNode("id" ),
                    @NamedAttributeNode( "bar" )})

     
 @NamedEntityGraph( name = "foo.without.details",
                     attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode( "id" ) } )
public class Foo{
```

The repository

```
 @Override    
 @EntityGraph( value = "foo.without.details" )   
 Page<Foo> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable );
```

If i use the second entityGraph is get follow error

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-6114] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.8.v20201217-ecdf3c32c4): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException │
│ Exception Description: You must define a fetch group manager at descriptor (Foo) in order to set a fetch group on the query (null) │
│ Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Aspect sql="SELECT id FROM foo WHERE (description LIKE ? ESCAPE ? AND (tenant_id = ?)) ORDER BY id ASC") │
│ FetchGroup(foo.without.details){} │
│ at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:493) │
│ at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.getResultList(AbstractJPAQuery.java:160)
```

What I also tried, is to use the wrapper annotation'NamedEntityGraphs' and to annotate the spring data repository.

```
   @Override
   @EntityGraph( attributePaths = "id" )
   Page<Foo> findAll( Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable );
```

Without the second EntityGraph all works:

Static weaving with Maven is enabled and logging is enabled

Anybody an idea what is wrong?

EDIT: weving Info

```
[INFO] --- eclipselink-maven-plugin:2.7.5.1:weave (default) @ 
[INFO] Only entities from base packages 'foo' will be included in persistence.xml 
[INFO] Entities found : 12 
[INFO] persistence.xml location: [INFO] Eclipselink weaving completed
```

Class file

```
public class Foo implements PersistenceWeaved,PersistenceObject, PersistenceWeavedFetchGroups, PersistenceWeavedLazy, PersistenceWeavedChangeTracking
```

Comment: the annotations seem off - could just be the formatting or a mis copy+paste, or that you have them wrong on your class. See https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs003.html which shows how to have multiple NamedEntityGraph definitions within a NamedEntityGraphs, as problems in the annotations might mean they aren't getting picked up at all by the persistence unit. This should show up as warnings and errors in the logs if you turn on EclipseLink logging https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the anwer. I tried this annotation, but nothing changed. This wrapper annotation is needed before java 8. Since Java 8 this wrapper annoation is not necessary.

Comment: Is the ` EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH` maybe a issue? I i use  EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD it works, but then a lot of unessary data are selected. How can i check that the weaving works correct?
I see in the logs
[INFO] --- eclipselink-maven-plugin:2.7.5.1:weave (default) @ 
[INFO] Only entities from base packages 'foo' will be included in persistence.xml
[INFO] Entities found : 12
[INFO] persistence.xml location: 
[INFO] Eclipselink weaving completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the maven version. Upgrade to a new maven version and all works fine!